MAUI DEP1000 AppX folder Issue
When trying to run a MAUI app in VS2022, I'm getting an error popup with the following error in the output console:

DEP1000: Cannot copy file "C:\temp\New folder\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\resources.pri" to layout "C:\temp\New folder\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\resources.pri". IOException - Cannot create "C:\temp\New folder\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX" because a file or directory with the same name already exists. [0x800700B7]

I've tried reinstalling the MAUI workload, reinstalling the dotnet SDK, reinstalling MAUI in the VS installer, and nothing seems to fix it.

Did you test with a new default maui project template?

The default template seems to work

@jonbooraem 1. You can try to copy the project to C:\ to see if it works. 2. You can also clean the bin and obj folder and try to rebuild your solution/project.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT I tried both steps and I'm still getting the same error. The only workaround I've found so far was starting a new project and copying everything over to that

@jonbooraem Thanks for the response, I think it's related with VS. You can see my answer below. :)

For now, to fix the issue, you can create a new project and copy everything over to the new one as you said.
Also, it's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn
